# Weird Behavior of Jquery Children

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first children call alerts the id of the form's direct children which is ul's id : "mainId". As far as I understand then this is the expected behavior of children but the second call subscribes the change event of both checkboxes which are not the direct children of the form. How come?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(function() 
{

    $('.triggers').children().each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });

    $(".triggers").children().change(function(e){
        alert(e.target.name)
    });
})
</script>

</head>

<body>


<form class="triggers" action="/askOrtal">
<ul id="mainId"> 
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="theCheckbox1"></li> 
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="theCheckbox2"></li> 
 <li><input type="submit" value="ClickMe"></li>
 <ul>
 </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The change event is bubbling up from the input to the li and then the ul. http://learn.jquery.com/events/

Comment: so this actually binds the onchange event of the ul ?

Comment: Yes, the event is bound on the UL, so when the event bubbles up the dom and reaches the UL, the handler is called. This is the principle that event delegation is based on.

Comment: so all the change events of the checkboxes bubble up to the UL ? do you have a link for this jquery behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: Well, it isn't a jQuery behavior, that's how events work in JavaScript.

Comment: Useful resource: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html.